# Shortcode attribute value with dash (hyphen)

Tags: shortcode

Is it safe to use hyphen in shortcode attribute value?

For example:

```
[foo something="fo-bar"]
```

Comment: You asked about **shortcode attribute values**, however, you've accepted the answer that's about shortcode tag or name. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's safe, you won't have any problem using it, the only caution about **Hyphens** and **Shortcodes** comes from the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Hyphens).

> Take caution when using hyphens in the name of your shortcodes. In the
>   following instance WordPress may see the second opening shortcode as
>   equivalent to the first (basically WordPress sees the first part
>   before the hyphen):

```
[tag]
[tag-a]
```

> It all depends on which shortcode is defined first. If you are going
>   to use hyphens then define the shortest shortcode first.
>
> To avoid this, use an underscore or simply no separator:

```
[tag_a]
```

Comment: Please note that the question is really about **attribute values**, not about shortcode naming. The OP accepted this answer, but it may confuse future visitors.

Comment: @Fayaz Thanks for the comment. I would have missed that.

Answer (score 8):

> **tl;dr;** Dash (hyphen) `-` is safe to use within shortcode **attribute values**.

---

### Rules for Shortcode attribute values:

For shortcode **attribute values**, anything **other than the following** four is usually fine:

1. There shouldn't be any square brackets `[` or `]`, e.g. `[foo bar='baa]z']`
2. There shouldn't be single quote within single quote, e.g. `[foo bar='baa'z']`
3. There shouldn't be double quote within double quote, e.g. `[foo bar="baa"z"]`
4. Back slash `\` will be escaped.

---

So the following example shortcode attribute values are just fine:

```
// dash or hyphen is fine
[foo bar='baa-z']
// Double quote within single quote is fine
[foo bar='baa"z']
// single quote within double quote is fine
[foo bar="baa'z"]
// space is fine
[foo bar='baa z']
// use double back slash to get single back slash 
[foo bar='baa\\z']
```

### Quote from [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Attributes):

> Attribute values must never contain the following characters:
>
> Square braces: `[ ]`
>
> Quotes: `" '`
>
> Unquoted values also must never contain spaces.
>
> HTML characters `<` and `>` have only limited support in attributes.
>
> The recommended method of escaping special characters in shortcode attributes is HTML encoding. Most importantly, any user input appearing in a shortcode attribute must be escaped or stripped of special characters.
>
> Note that double quotes are allowed inside of single-quoted values and vice versa, however this is not recommended when dealing with user input.
>
> The following characters, if they are not escaped within an attribute value, will be automatically stripped and converted to spaces:
>
> No-break space: `\xC2\xA0`
>
> Zero-width space: `\xE2\x80\x8B`